# STM32L4P5 - load multiple registers and interrupts

Tags: stm32, interrupt

STM32L4P5 - I understand that a "load multiple registers" takes multiple clock cycles to execute. can an interrupt break in the middle of this or does it wait till after the set of loads is complete?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can interrupt in the middle of it, and the instruction will be re-started (or continued) once the interrupt completes.

This is basically harmless, unless you are doing an LDM from a memory-mapped peripheral, in which case some registers may be read more than once, possibly having unintended side-effects.

This is more a question about the ARM core, rather than the STM32. Some information [specific to Cortex-M4](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Exceptions/Exception-handling). And about [ARMv7-M](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0403/d/System-Level-Architecture/System-Level-Programmers--Model/ARMv7-M-exception-model/Exceptions-in-Load-Multiple-and-Store-Multiple-operations).

Answer (score 0):

One of the registers automatically stacked by Cortex-M is the xPSR or Program Status Register. It contains flags such as carry bit, as well as some state bits for multiple load/store instructions. Multiple load/store can be safely interrupted and resumed upon ISR exit.

You can read about it in [Cortex-M7 Architecture Reference Manual, page 448](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Eprabal/teaching/eecs373-f10/readings/ARMv7-M_ARM.pdf)

It interrupts multiple load/store and restarts it upon ISR exit.

For more details, check out interrupt entry/exit procedure in the very same document.

For clarity: a single RAM access also takes more than 1 clock cycle (typically 2, can be 3, non-deterministic in real life application with interrupts and traffic on CPU AXIM bus). TCM (Tightly coupled memory) and cache have 1 clock cycle access.